# Compare two result sets if employee Id is matches change status flag to true

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

Can anyone kindly provide the DataWeave logic for the below output structure based on the two Inputs resultSet1 and resultSet2. if the id is matched change the status to **true** and by default, the status is **false**?

resultSet1 = [{
id: "12334",
},
{
id: "13357",
}
]

resultSet2 = [
{
id: "12334",
status: false
},
{
id: "11521",
status: false
},
{
id: "13357",
status: false
}

final output:
[
{
id: "12334",
status: true
},
{
id: "11521",
status: false
},
{
id: "13357",
status: true
}
]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

this solution iterates `resultSet2` and for each item checks if the ID is in the list of IDs of `resultSet1`

```
resultSet2 map {
        id: $.id,
        status: resultSet1.id contains $.id
     }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: It basically iterates the resultSet2 and for each item checks if the ID is in the list of IDs of the first resultSet (resultSet1.id)

Comment: Add it to the answer itself please.